# MySQL current_date and current_time fetch in a single query at midnight

Tags: mysql

I use a single query to update two columns date and time. But, at midnight, in some instances it inserts the time value of the previous day and date value of the following day. I guess this may be caused by an internal query processing delay and would like to know whether there is any alternative in place of using current_timestamp().

Sample result
start time : 2016/01/13 23:59:59 (this should be as 2016/01/12 23:59:59) 
end time   : 2016/01/13 00:00:01

Comment: Can you show your insert query?

Comment: in that case i would suggest you to use PHP date time store it in variable and save it using query.